# Opengl mono for android

Tags: android, opengl-es, xna

I'm trying to convert an XNA project to Android. I saw a video saying  I need to have "opengl mono for android" as an option when creating project, but I don't.
Can anyone tell me how to download this extension?

Comment: Check out my answer, and if it answered your question feel free to accept it as an answer!    
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22297547/3239917

Answer (score 0):

Use *MonoGame*.If you don't you will need to rewrite your game including all the rendering logic in either C# using Xamarin.Android or a complete rewrite in Java.

So your best choice would be Monogame:

monogame.net

**EDIT**

I just found this on an other site it's called exen, but I still think *Monogame* is a better one because there are many people using it.
link to *Exen*:

http://andrewrussell.net/exen/